# Background shape of CSS on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Bootstrap navigation like in the snippet below.

I have noticed different users just going to the heading and not actually going into the submenu to select products.

When I expand the products section and hover over the headings I want the orange background to be shaped like an arrow to try show people that they can go across. Something like this:

[image]

[image]

I tried messing around with shapes in pure CSS using the border as shown here https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/ but cannot achieve what I am looking for.

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu{
  background-color:#eee;
}
.navbar .dropdown-submenu{
  display:none;
  background-color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:100%;
}
.navbar .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-item > a{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item > a{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-item:hover .dropdown-submenu{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:focus, .navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color:#F8981D;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="Lifting365 Menu" class="icon">
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#1">Heading1›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#2">Heading2›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#3">Heading3›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### Edit

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu{
  background-color:#eee;
}
.navbar .dropdown-submenu{
  display:none;
  background-color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:100%;
}
.navbar .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-item > a{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item > a{
 display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-item:hover .dropdown-submenu{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:focus, .navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color:orange;
}


.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative; 
  /* having this with relative positioning means my menu items are not aligned at the top the way they should be and I also don't want to give fixed widths or heights as the content is dynamic.*/
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:hover:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid orange;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  z-index:9999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="Lifting365 Menu" class="icon">
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#1">Heading1›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#2">Heading2›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#3">Heading3›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu{
  background-color:#eee;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar .dropdown-submenu{
  display:none;
  background-color:#ddd;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:100%;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:focus, .navbar .dropdown-menu{
  position: inherit;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:focus, .navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item{
    transition: .5s ease width;
    width: 95%;
}

.navbar .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-item > a{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item > a{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-item:hover .dropdown-submenu{
  display:block;
}
.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:focus, .navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color:#F8981D;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:focus, .navbar .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-item:hover:after{
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -28px;
  left: 9%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 13px solid #F8981D;
  border-top: 16px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 16px solid transparent;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="Lifting365 Menu" class="icon">
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#1">Heading1›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#2">Heading2›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#3">Heading3›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**Explanation:**

Basically the shape is copied from the link that you gave.

Then add `transition: 1s ease all;` to the main shape. And on `:hover` makes the elements width bigger.

Then you get this:

```css
.arrow{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.arrow:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid orange;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.arrow:hover{
  width: 250px;
}

.arrow:hover a{
  color: red;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
```

---

**You could add:**

If you want the arrow to only appear on hover, change `.arrow:before{...}` to `.arrow:hover:before{...}`

```css
.arrow{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  transition: 1s ease all;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.arrow:hover:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid orange;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.arrow:hover{
  width: 250px;
}

.arrow:hover a{
  color: red;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
```

---

**Or add:**

If you want the orange background to appear on hover as well.
Add

```
.arrow:hover{
    background: orange;
}
```

And remove `background: orange;` from the `.arrow{...}`. Also change `transition: 1s ease all;` to `transition: 1s ease width;`

```css
.arrow{
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s ease width;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.arrow:hover{
  background: orange;
}

.arrow a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.arrow:hover:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid orange;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.arrow:hover{
  width: 250px;
}

.arrow:hover a{
  color: red;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
<div class="arrow"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, unfortunately this won't work in my menu. I'll edit the original question with updated code so you can see

Comment: @PaddyHallihan I used your code now, see "**Using your code:**" solution

Comment: thanks for your help with this, the main issue I have is that I want the products submenu to line up with the top of the headings menu so I can't use relative positioning.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan what do you mean exactly? Btw the first code snippet is the one with your code now.

Comment: If you run my first snippet you'll see that the submenu is aligned at the top `.navbar .dropdown-submenu{position:absolute;top:0px;}`

Comment: @PaddyHallihan I changed it, the arrow is a little bit off right now but this is as close as I can get without `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `clip-path` to make shapes like this.

**DEMO**

```css
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.navbar .dropdown-submenu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

.navbar .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-item>a {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-item>a {
  display: block;
  padding: .25rem 1.5rem;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item:hover .dropdown-submenu {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-item {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-item a:focus,
.navbar .dropdown-menu>.dropdown-item a:hover {
  background-color: #F8981D;
  clip-path: polygon(95% 0%, 100% 50%, 95% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 54%, 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <img src="media/icons/menu.png" alt="Lifting365 Menu" class="icon">
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item text-center dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav dropdown-toggle products-dropdown" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#1">Heading1›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#2">Heading2›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item d-block">
            <a class="submenu-item" href="store#3">Heading3›</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-submenu">
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item d-block"><a href="#">Product</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="about">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item text-center"><a class="nav-link nav" href="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, however, this means that my submenu will not show at all

Comment: @PaddyHallihan have edited the code. Thanks for pointing out.